# Why aren't the two code blocks equivalent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've got these two javascript code blocks interacting with remote api:

first:

```
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`;
    const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`};
    return axios.get(url, headers).then(res => {console.log(res.data.data)}).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

^ getting status code 401

second:

```
 const options = {
  url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`,
  method: 'get',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`}
};
return axios(options).then(res => {console.log(res.data.data)}).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
```

^ getting status code 200

My question is why both code blocks don't behave the same ? They appear to do same job.

Comment: Are the logs in the network tab equivalent?

Comment: I think you are calling `axios.get` incorrectly. The documentation says the optional second parameter of `axios.get` should be an axios configuration (like `options` in your second example). You are instead giving it headers.

Comment: I'm using `axios.get()` in my other project and it works fine.

Comment: Yes but you aren't using it correctly here. You can't pass it the headers directly, you need to pass it a configuration.

Comment: headers  should be 
```
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`;
    const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`};
    return axios.get(url, {headers}).then(res => {console.log(res.data.data)}).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

```
because its an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `axios.get` should be an axios configuration, not headers directly. The configuration of course can include headers. Try this modified example of the first attempt and see if it resolves your issue.

```
const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`;
const myHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`};
return axios.get(url, { headers: myHeaders }).then(res => {console.log(res.data.data)}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Yes. You're correct. As soon as I passed in the headers as an object (with brackets) I got 200 on the first block too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [their docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro) they state `axios.get(...)` is an alias for `axios(...)` with some predefined behavior. As mentioned in the comments you're passing in the `headers` object into what should be a [request config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) object.

So, this should fix the issue:

```js
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`;
    const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`}
    return axios.get(url, { headers }).then(res => {console.log(res.data.data)}).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```